# Running Spring boot test against Apache Camel Route with jUnit5

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

We have an Apache Camel route consuming messages from an IBM MQ request queue and sending messages back to a response queue. It will look like below:

```
from("jms:request.queue")
    .routeId("my-route")
    .process(myProcessor)
    .to("jms:response.queue").id("response")
    .log("work done")
```

No need to say that the above example is heavily simplified. In reality it is relatively complex using some `filter` and `choice` constructs as well as two internal `direct` sub routes. The complexity makes you want to have unit tests in place to make sure the expected functionality is there.

To avoid connecting to a JMS broker and have the test still verify the end to end flow the easiest way would be to mock the entry and the output endpoints using `AdviceWith` provided by Camel. Our environment configuration is driven from `yaml` files, and our unit tests looks like below:

```
@CamelSpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    CamelConfig.class,
    JmsConfig.class
    ...
    // many other classes required to build the application context for this route
},
// The initialiser below is needed to load yaml configuration 
initializers = ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = IbmMqConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@UseAdviceWith
class MyRouteTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private MyRouteBuilder myRouteBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext;

    @EndpointInject(uri="mock:response-queue")
    private MockEndpoint mockResponseQueue;

    @Produce("direct:start")
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Test
    void shouldWorkAsExpected() {
        AdviceWith.adviceWith("my-route"), camelContext,  new AdviceWithRouteBuilder(camelContext) {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                replaceFromWith("direct:start");
                weaveById("response").replace().to(mockReesponseQueue);
            }
        });
        // The rest of the test goes here
    }

}
```

In other words what I done above was to follow the [Apache Camel Spring testing documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/others/test-spring-junit5.html) . The only difference I had was that rather than specifying the configuration via `@SpringBootTest` annotation I used `@ContextConfiguration` instead. This was because I wanted to to be able to load `yaml` config file.

My problem is that when trying to run the test the camel context is not started and the route is not configured. It is only when explicitly calling `camelContext.start()` that the route is actually started. When using jUnit 4 and the old `RunWith` approach we never had to do this and everything worked perfectly.

So my question is what I am doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually the normal behavior when you annotate your test class with `@UseAdviceWith`. Indeed by doing so, you indicate `camel-test-spring-junit5` that you want to alter the routes consequently it cannot start the context automatically as they need to be altered before starting the context.

See the [Javadoc of `UseAdviceWith` for more details](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-test-spring/latest/org/apache/camel/test/spring/UseAdviceWith.html), I quote:

> Indicates the use of adviceWith() within the test class. If a class is
> annotated with this annotation and value() returns true, any
> CamelContexts bootstrapped during the test through the use of Spring
> Test loaded application contexts will not be started automatically.
> The test author is responsible for injecting the Camel contexts into
> the test and executing CamelContextLifecycle.start() on them at the
> appropriate time after any advice has been applied to the routes in
> the Camel context(s).